# Using Hebrew characters in string

Tags: r, character, hebrew

I would like to use Hebrew characters in string in R.
I used the following:

```
> a<-c("משה")
> a
[1] "îùä"
> class (a)
[1] "character"
```

As can be seen I get Jibbrish when I output the content of the string or using any functions. How can I use Hebrew characters?

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me. Are you on Windows? If so, my condolences — it may not be easy to achieve this.

Comment: > a<-c("משה")
> a
[1] "משה"
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.11 (El Capitan)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

Comment: @Shawn Mehan, I use Windows. Here is my sessioninfo():  > sessionInfo() 
R version 3.2.1 Patched (2015-07-16 r68681)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Hebrew_Israel.1255  LC_CTYPE=Hebrew_Israel.1255    LC_MONETARY=Hebrew_Israel.1255
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                   LC_TIME=Hebrew_Israel.1255

Comment: Did you get any joy with Richard's suggestion of `Encoding`. You can man it in RStudio via `> ?Encoding`

Comment: I would like to use Hebrew freely with English. Without any need to encode every time I use Hebrew.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to all the comments here is the answer:
If I use it as is, I get Jibbrish:

```
> a<-"משה"
> a
[1] "îùä"
```

However if I encode it to UTF8 I get the right result:

```
> a<-enc2utf8( "משה")
> a
[1] "משה"
```

I wish there was a way to do it without encoding.