# Non English (Hebrew) output in RStudio console

Tags: r, rstudio, utf8-decode, non-english

The following test works fine on my laptop, but produces an error on my HP EliteOne 800 running Windows 10

```
H <- "שלום"

H
```

In the machine with the problem I get

> [1] "ùìåí"

I tested several encoding, such as

```
Encoding(H)  <- "ISO-8859-1"
```

which gives the same output, and

```
Encoding(H)<-"UTF-8"
H
```

that produces

> [1] "\xf9\xec\xe5\xed"

Below is the response to

```
sessionInfo()
```

> R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14) Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
>   Running under: Windows 8 x64 (build 9200)
>
> locale: [1] LC_COLLATE=Hebrew_Israel.1255  LC_CTYPE=Hebrew_Israel.1255
>   LC_MONETARY=Hebrew_Israel.1255 [4] LC_NUMERIC=C
>   LC_TIME=Hebrew_Israel.1255
>
> attached base packages: [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils
>   datasets  methods   base
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached): [1] tools_3.2.2

Any help will be appreciated,

Avi

Comment: [This might help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33108388/using-hebrew-characters-in-string)

Comment: It appears you do not have the proper fonts installed to support that encoding. When I drop the first line of code into my Mac console it displays properly. My monospace font is "Courier". The information needed should be accessible with `help(pac=grDevices)`

Answer (score 4):

Thank you Richard, you led me to a solution that works -- although I do not understand why.  I played with various codes, and accidentally changed my locale to Japanese and **it works**.  Than I tested various other locales and they do the same trick.  If any one knows why the Hebrew does not work with Hebrew locale, I would like to know.  Below is the code and its product:

> ```
> H <- "שלום"
> H
> Sys.getlocale()
>
> Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "Hebrew")
>
> H <- "שלום"
> H
> Sys.getlocale()
>
> Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "ja")
> H <- "שלום"
> H
>
> Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "Portuguese_Brazil.1252")
> H <- "שלום"
> H
>
> Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "German")
> H <- "שלום"
> H produces the following output, where only the Hebrew locale does not show Hebrew.
> ```
>
> > H <- "שלום"
> >
> > H
>
> **> [1] "ùìåí"** #THE PROBLEM IN HEBREW
>
> > Sys.getlocale()
>
> [1]"LC_COLLATE=Hebrew_Israel.1255;LC_CTYPE=Hebrew_Israel.1255;LC_MONETARY=Hebrew_Israel.1255;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Hebrew_Israel.1255"
>
> > Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "Hebrew")
>
> [1]"LC_COLLATE=Hebrew_Israel.1255;LC_CTYPE=Hebrew_Israel.1255;LC_MONETARY=Hebrew_Israel.1255;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Hebrew_Israel.1255"
>
> > H <- "שלום"
> >     H
>
> **> [1] "ùìåí"** #THE PROBLEM IN HEBREW
>
> > Sys.getlocale()
>
> [1]LC_COLLATE=Hebrew_Israel.1255;LC_CTYPE=Hebrew_Israel.1255;LC_MONETARY=Hebrew_Israel.1255;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Hebrew_Israel.1255"
>
> > Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "ja")
>
> [1]"LC_COLLATE=Japanese_Japan.932;LC_CTYPE=Japanese_Japan.932;LC_MONETARY=Japanese_Japan.932;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Japanese_Japan.932"
>
> **> H <- "שלום"** #THE SOLUTION IN OTHER LANGUAGE THAT WORKS -- ALSO SEE BELOW
>
> > H
>
> [1] "שלום"
>
> > Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "Portuguese_Brazil.1252") [1]"LC_COLLATE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252;LC_CTYPE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252;LC_MONETARY=Portuguese_Brazil.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Portuguese_Brazil.1252"
> >
> > H <- "שלום"
> >
> > H
>
> [1] "שלום"
>
> > Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "German") [1]"LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252;LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252;LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252"
> >
> > H <- "שלום"
> >
> > H
>
> [1] "שלום"